# GDAL make configure wrong:PROJ 6 symbols not found

Tags: gdal

err tip is :

```
checking for PROJ >= 6 library... checking for proj_create_from_wkt in -lproj... no
checking for proj_create_from_wkt in -lproj... no
checking for proj_create_from_wkt in -lproj... no
checking for internal_proj_create_from_wkt in -lproj... no
checking for internal_proj_create_from_wkt in -lproj... no
checking for internal_proj_create_from_wkt in -linternalproj... no
checking for internal_proj_create_from_wkt in -linternalproj... (cached) no
configure: error: PROJ 6 symbols not found
```

The config detail info is:

```
configure:19168: result: no, consider installing GNU libiconv
configure:19414: Bash completions not requested
configure:19564: checking for PROJ >= 6 library
configure:19794: checking for proj_create_from_wkt in -lproj
configure:19819: arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -std=c++11 -o conftest -mthumb -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden  -march=armv7-a -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 conftest.cpp -lproj  -L/usr/local//lib -lproj -lsqlite3   -lm -ldl -lsupc++ -lstdc++ >&5
/home/tang/android-toolchain/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: warning: skipping incompatible /usr/local//lib/libproj.so while searching for proj
/home/tang/android-toolchain/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lproj
/home/tang/android-toolchain/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: warning: skipping incompatible /usr/local//lib/libproj.so while searching for proj
/home/tang/android-toolchain/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lproj
/home/tang/android-toolchain/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: warning: skipping incompatible /usr/local//lib/libsqlite3.so while searching for sqlite3
/home/tang/android-toolchain/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lsqlite3
/tmp/ccC8sqRS.o:conftest.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'proj_create_from_wkt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am very confused that i hava install proj and sqlite3 already!
The proj info is below:

```
tang@tang-VirtualBox:~$ proj
Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
usage: proj [-bdeEfiIlmorsStTvVwW [args]] [+opt[=arg] ...] [file ...]
```

besides,i am very sure that i have tried many times to test configure file,bellow:

```
CFLAGS="-mthumb" CXXFLAGS="-mthumb" LIBS="-lsupc++ -lstdc++" ./configure --prefix=/home/tang/gdal/Android --host=arm-linux-androideabi --with-proj=/usr/local/include --with-unix-stdio-64=no --with-ogr --with-geos --with-hide-internal-symbols --with-libz=internal --with-threads --without-bsb --without-cfitsio --without-cryptopp --without-curl --without-dwgdirect --without-ecw --without-expat --without-fme --without-freexl --without-gif --without-gif --without-gnm --without-grass --without-grib --without-hdf4 --without-hdf5 --without-idb --without-ingres --without-jasper --without-jp2mrsid --without-jpeg --without-kakadu --without-libgrass --without-libkml --without-libtool --without-mrf --without-mrsid --without-mysql --without-netcdf --without-odbc --without-ogdi --without-openjpeg --without-pcidsk --without-pcraster --without-pcre --without-perl --without-pg --without-php --without-png --without-python --without-qhull --without-sde --without-sqlite3 --without-webp --without-xerces --without-xml2
```